# How to show only required parametrs in Swagger-UI "Value" field

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, swagger-ui

I have `Post` method. `Swagger-Ui` by default generates example query in `JSON` with all `fields` from `Class`.

I want to show there by default only none-optional fields.

In `Swagger-Ui` `Model` i clearly see that:

```
x (integer, optional),
y (string),
```

Some fields are optional and some are not.

How can i achieve that in `Spring MVC` `Spring Boot app` ?

My Swagger Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig
{
    @Bean
    public Docket api()
    {

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).

                select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any()).paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/**")).build();

    }
}
```

`@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)`

hides the field - but i do not want that.
I only want to make `Swagger` generate JSON when i click `Model Schema` only based on None-optional fields.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a feature of Swagger UI and therefore there's no way to configure it to behave like you're asking.  So consider modifying the source code to do what you're asking for in the swagger-ui project

Comment: Is there alternative i.e generate my post in Swagger Ui for each http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation with its model or something else that could satisfy me?

Answer (score 0):

Mark your model with `Jackson's` `@JsonIgnoreProperties` e.g.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"field1", ...})
public class YourModel {

    private String field1;

    private String field2;

    //getters and setters here
}
```

to test, assuming `field1` is `null`

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
YourModel model = new YourModel();

String strField1 = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(objectMapper);

assertThat(strField1, not(containsString("field1")));
```

See [@JsonIgnoreProperties](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html).

Comment: Unfortunately after clicking `Model Schema`
i am still seeing `optional` fields in the `Swagger UI Parameter` `value`. So this does not fix the issue.

Comment: This is more about how to config `Swagger Ui` that way. Not how to send `POST` with only not null fields.

Comment: I have updated the answer.  I was using Swagger before and to exclude some of the fields in my model from displaying in the UI I've used this annotation.  I remember that the `@ApiModelProperty` has a hidden attribute that might help you.

Comment: I tried that but first of all i see all fields in `Model.
Second i do not want to hide them - i only want to make `Swagger`
generate `JSON` only based on `Not-optional` fields.
`  @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)`
hides the field - but i do not want that.

I appreciate the try though :)